# Unable to use mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am coding a simple registration form using mongoose.
I have use a javascript file to process the values of the registration form.

Here is my **registrationButtonAction.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var User = require('/models/Mongoose Database/user_database');
    // this line is causing the problem


    var registerButton = document.getElementById("registerMe");
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    var usernameRegister = document.getElementById("usernameRegister");
    var passwordRegister = document.getElementById("passwordRegister");
    var repasswordRegister = document.getElementById("repasswordRegister");


    registerButton.onclick = function () {

       if(!firstName.value || !passwordRegister.value || !repasswordRegister.value || !usernameRegister.value){
           alert("Enter all required fields");
       }else if (passwordRegister.value != repasswordRegister.value){
            alert("Passwords must match");
       }else {
           var newUser = new User({
                       username : usernameRegister.value,
                       password : passwordRegister.value
                   });
               User.find({username:usernameRegister.value}, function (error, user) {

                       if (error) throw error;

                       if(user){
                           window.location("/register");
                       }else {
                           newUser.save(function (error) {
                               if(error) throw error;
                           });
                           window.location("/login");
                       }
                       // user.comparePassword(passwordRegister.value, function (error, isMatch) {
                       //     if (error) throw error;
                       //
                       //     return 1;

                       //})
               });

       }

    }


}
```

When I comment the var `User = require('/models/Mongoose Database/user_database');`, all the checks are working fine inside the onclick function. But when I uncomment it, it is not recognizing the button click.

I want to know whether this is a correct way of taking values from the registration page and storing them in a mongoose database.

Comment: aren't you mixing server and client code? your models should not be accessible from the client. create a REST API to modify your db server-side

Comment: @num8er we've all been beginners, nothing laughable about it

Comment: @xShirase thanks for pointing that out. So I have to learn about making api first then. something like this ? https://hackhands.com/mongodb-crud-mvc-way-with-passport-authentication/

Comment: @xShirase People going to SO   with funny questions without reading documentations, watching tutorials. Why to make SO to look like garbage?  Also Sharad, go to YouTube, there are tons of video tutorials, search: `nodejs ejs mongoose tutorial`

Comment: @num8er yeah, thanks for the advice. Just needed a guidance from experienced coders :)

Comment: @num8er I completely agree with you in general (omg the things I've seen in my review thread...), but OP has taken the time to debug his problem, asks politely, and gives us a properly formatted post with correct grammar. His question stems from confusion but I don't believe it should be dismissed as 'garbage'. Let's keep SO friendly, FFS!

Comment: @xShirase the feeling of being laugh by someone drives me to be better, to learn stuff myself without asking anybody. So it's just a pedagogical action. (:

Comment: @xShirase would You try to give normal title for his question? Cuz somebody will come to this page from google search and will downvote him also (:

Comment: @num8er I know... I now find myself in the position of the 'pedantic anti-fun SO user', that feels strange! I blame the fact that I've been through too many reviews of real garbage questions today.

Comment: @xShirase everything is fine my friend (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing server and client code. Mongoose models and Node.js functions are not accessible inside window.onload on your client.

To put it simply, you need to create a REST API to perform database operations on the server. You have all the right tools aready, just need to reorder them.

The flow would be as such :

- get the values entered in the browser
- call an endpoint on your server (for example /api/createUser)
- in the express router, have a route called /api/createUser in which you can access your User model and perform creation/deletion/update, etc.

My suggestion would be for you to go through [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) which should remove your confusion and bring you up to speed in no time. Good Luck!

Also, Passport can help you with authentication, but I believe you should first learn how to build a basic API. Authentication is a tricky beast ;)

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Accepting the answer coz thats what i was looking for, a way to perform all this operations.